# What is the correct way to AND in python?

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm trying to send the following serial commands in python, but all I have is the following code from the datasheet.

Datasheet:

```
Putc(128); 
Putc(0); 
Putc(40); 
Putc((128 + 0 + 40) & 127);
```

My code (which does not work, but I can successfully send serial commands):

```
ser.write(chr(128))
ser.write(chr(8))
ser.write(chr(40))
ser.write(chr((128+0+40) & 127))
```

Is there something I should be using other than the & symbol?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The datasheet has `Putc(0)`, you're doing `ser.write(chr(8))`. Is that just a typo in the question or is your actual code like that, too?

Comment: what is the desired output? not sure if you look for `logical and` or `bitwise and` or some other operator that is specified only for your Datasheet syntax..

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Putc" so I didn't use it.  It isn't a typo, but I'm open to changing my code if I'm doing it in a sloppy way.

Comment: And the data sheet says the last number is the checksum: "The checksum should be added with all unsigned 8 bit integers, and then ANDed with the mask 0b01111111 (decimal 127) in an 8 bit system."  I'm not sure how to do this other than what I tried above.

Comment: that's [bitwise](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) => `&` symbol is appropriate for your case ;) back to @Padraic's question, what is the problem - what error message do you see? or you just typoed 8 instead of 0 as @dano is suggesting?

Comment: But you write `128`, **`8`** and `40`and you add `128`, **`0`**, and `40`.

Comment: In C (libc) there is a function (really a C macro) called `putc`.

Comment: I wasn't saying you should use `Putc`, I was saying you were using 8 instead of 0, as @Matthias also stated.

Comment: Yes, other than the obvious typo (thanks!), my code doesn't seem to be working.  This is going to a motor controller that is expecting packetized serial as an input.  I had assume it was the AND command.

Comment: Do I need to send the checksum or last command in binary?   "The checksum should be added with all unsigned 8 bit integers, and then ANDed with the mask 0b01111111 (decimal 127) in an 8 bit system."

Comment: The checksum should probably be a single character just like all the other data bytes. And obviously if you don't add the actual bytes you sent, you're going to get a wrong checksum and the controller will reject it. The `&` does a bitwise and which is exactly what you need. If fixing the typo didn't help then you aren't providing enough information for anyone to help. P.S. To avoid confusion you should edit the question to be *exactly* the same as the code you're testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do a bitwise *and* in Python is what you are using:

```
x & y
```

For example:

```
1 & 2
#>>> 0

6 & 4
#>>> 4

3 & 2
#>>> 2
```

You can test this from the Python shell.